# Conditional image import with Webpack in Rails 6

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, image, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I am working on an application with Rails 6 / Webpack that uses different subdomains, and for each subdomain we associate different users, stylesheets, etc. I would like to import conditionally my project images depending on the domain. Currently, my `app/javascript/pack/application.js` do this for importing common images

```
require.context('../images',true)
```

However, if I create a separate folder for the images (let's say `images_subdomainfoo`)
and I attempt some conditional import like

```
const foo = import("images_subdomainfoo/bar.png")
```

this image is compiled **even when the file containing the statement is not imported** (for example, I placed that line in a `subdomainfoo.js` file and then added this line in my HTML header file

```
<%= javascript_pack_tag 'subdomainfoo', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' if request.subdomain == "foo" %>
```

but the image is loaded regardless the subdomain).

I've seen some approachs like the [NormalModuleReplacementPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/normal-module-replacement-plugin/) but I am not sure how to incorporate that into a Rails 6 application, since  it involves starting webpacker with special options like `npx webpack --env APP_TARGET=VERSION_A`

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the following line to your `_head.html.erb` (above `javascript_pack_tag`):

```
<script>
  window.subdomain = '<%= request.subdomain %>'
</script>
```

This would ensure that your subdomain-name is attached to the Global Object which is accessible in Javascript.

Then you can add the following line to your `app/javascript/pack/application.js` - assuming your images are placed inside folders named after your subdomains.

```js
const foo = import(`images_${window.subdomain}/bar.png`)
```